# Human sensible outputs from finverse

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, inverse

I am using `finverse` and it is giving strange simplifications as an example

```
>> syms x
>> f = -0.0185*x^2 + 12.4698;
>> finverse(f)

ans = 

(2^(1/2)*185^(1/2)*(62349 - 5000*x)^(1/2))/185
```

Rather than the much simpler

```
sqrt(12.4698 - x) / sqrt(0.0185)
```

Or something to that effect. Is there a way to force "human sensible outputs"? I tried `simplify` but it didn't help very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can used function [simple](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simple.html)

```
syms x
f = -0.0185*x^2 + 12.4698;
Z = finverse(f)
V = simple(Z);

Z =

(2^(1/2)*185^(1/2)*(62349 - 5000*x)^(1/2))/185

>> V

V =

(23069130 - 1850000*x)^(1/2)/185
```

Remove **;** at the end of   function calls, that to see at different simplification.

Comment: `>> V = simple(Z)
Error using sym/simple (line 7)
Function 'simple' has been removed. Use 'simplify' instead.
 
>> V = simplify(Z)
 
V =
 
(370^(1/2)*(62349 - 5000*x)^(1/2))/185`

Comment: @user1543042 , in this case use another function - combine. Hope her not remove.

Comment: They haven't removed it, but it doesn't change the output at all.